# Using GDAL to merge 3 bands to form a multispectral image?

Tags: gdal

I have 3 separate *.tif image files as grayscale. They are representing data acquired with a scanner. Each of them is a separate band of the scanner; red, green, and blue. I would like to reassemble them in a single RGB *.tif image file.

Using `gdal_merge.py -o RGB.tif -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB red.tif green.tif blue.tif`

doesn't work; I end up with a single grayscale image which size is the sum of all individual images.
How to achieve this simple operation?

(They are not geotiff, just simple tif files; there is no tfw)

Comment: Use `-separate: Place each input file into a separate band.` http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per user30184's comment, you can use gdal_merge like so:

```
gdal_merge.py -separate  -o new_rgb.tif -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB C:\input_r.tif C:\input_g.tif C:\input_b.tif
```

Answer (score 7):

I had MemoryError with `gdal_merge.py -separate ...` when used on big input. [Different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52343443/289827) helped my issue:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate RGB.vrt red.tif green.tif blue.tif
gdal_translate RGB.vrt RGB.tif
```

Comment: +1. You should always use VRT's when possible. They're much less of a memory-hog.

Comment: This was not the case for OP, but when merging GeoTiff files you may want to specify the CRS with e.g. `-a_srs epsg:1234` to avoid [further issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266093/geoserver-2-10-add-raster-data-source-could-not-list-layers-for-this-store).