# Geoserver 2.10 - Add Raster Data Source - Could not list layers for this store

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I want to  add a raster data source as a data store, based on a somewhat huge .tif file (> 200 MB, file permissions are correct). I select the respective file and when I save, I get an error:

```
    Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: 
Failed to create reader from file:data/geotiffs/tiffs/E/or11.tif and hints null
```

What can I do about that?

---

gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: or11.tif
       or11.tfW
Size is 6132, 10026
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (3456300.560000000055879,5559953.679999999701977)
Pixel Size = (0.080000000000009,-0.080000000000007)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2004:04:06 12:44:10
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop 7.0
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 3456300.560, 5559953.680) 
Lower Left  ( 3456300.560, 5559151.600) 
Upper Right ( 3456791.120, 5559953.680) 
Lower Right ( 3456791.120, 5559151.600) 
Center      ( 3456545.840, 5559552.640) 
Band 1 Block=6132x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6132x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6132x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: 200MB is far from being huge for a GeoTiff. That is not the problem. Could you add the output of gdalinfo for that file and the full error stacktrace from the geoserver.log  to the question ?

Comment: `Coordinate System is \`'` seems to be wrong.  What CRS does the file have? Can you assign it with `gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:XXXX`

Comment: When I assign it, do I have to use the CRS the file was originally created for or can I change it to the CRS I want the file to be used with after import?

Comment: You can also change it, but then you need gdalwarp ? What is the right CRS ?

Comment: Originally, it was EPSG:31467, but I need it in EPSG:4326

Answer (score 5):

Your file seems to be missing a Coordinate Reference System (CRS). You need to  add it to the data.

Just assign the SRS to the dataset:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:31467 or11.tif or11_31467.tif
```

-OR-

Change the CRS:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:31467 -t_srs EPSG:4326 or11.tif or11_4326.tif
```

---

**Some performance hints**:

Your data has blocksize of "Block=6132x1", which is not very good performance-wise. Add the following to either of the commands

```
-co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512
```

For more performance improvement you should create overviews using `gdaladdo`

Comment: How can I install gdal_translate and gdalwarp in windows?

Comment: If gdalinfo works you should already have the other tools. I don't know exactly how to call them in Windows... I'm sure you'll find out ;-)